# How to create a Logitech script to simulate rapid key presses when a specific key is held down?

Tags: lua, scripting, mouse, logitech-gaming-software

I am working on a Logitech scripting project in Lua, where I need to achieve the following behavior:

When I hold down the left arrow, right arrow, up arrow, or down arrow key on a non-Logitech keyboard and then press the 'sniper button' on my Logitech G502 X Wireless mouse, I want the held arrow key to be rapidly pressed twice in succession.

I have created the following script, but I'm unsure about the correct syntax or keywords to achieve the desired behavior:

```lua
local arrowKey = nil

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "G_PRESSED" then
      if arg == LEFT_ARROW or arg == RIGHT_ARROW or arg == UP_ARROW or arg == DOWN_ARROW then
         arrowKey = arg
      elseif arg == MOUSE_KEY and arrowKey ~= nil then
         PressKey(arrowKey)
         Sleep(20)
         PressKey(arrowKey)
      end
   elseif event == "G_RELEASED" then
      if arg == arrowKey then
         arrowKey = nil
      end
   end
end
```

Could someone please guide me on how to properly achieve this behavior using Logitech scripting in Lua? Is there a better approach or any modifications I should make to my current script?

### Thank you in advance for your help!

I do not know the correct syntax or keywords to achieve the desired behavior,

LEFT_ARROW, RIGHT_ARROW, UP_ARROW, DOWN_ARROW and MOUSE_KEY are just placeholders for the correct code that should be used (if this will even work )

Comment: Your task is impossible: LGS/GHub doesnot see the statuses of usual keyboard keys (letters, digits, arrows).  Only mouse buttons, special G-keys on Logitech keyboard and modifier keys (Shift, Alt, Ctrl on any keyboard) are visible to the Lua script.  Try to write AutoHotKey script for your task (create another SO question and set `autohotkey` tag).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, appreciate it.